# ACTION_GET_CONTENT to Google Images

Tags: android, android-intent

As the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) say: "ACTION_GET_CONTENT could allow the user to browse over the web and download the desired data".
And that's what I need, from Google Images. Although, if I use this intent's type the app crashes (I suppose it only expects ACTION_VIEW to open the browser):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
```

It needs to (edited to clarify what I need):

- Estabilish the connection to the web browser
- The URL to Google Images
- Retrieve the image's URL after the user has chosen one (it needs to close the browser, the ACTION_VIEW just keeps on going until the user decides to close it and does not retrieve any information).

As far the URL I have is this one, but it needs something else because it is going to a default search, not for images:

```
String url = "http://images.google.com/search?q=" + imagename;
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following url. It works fine for me in my app:

```
"http://images.google.com/search?num=10&hl=en&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=980&bih=710&q=" + YourQueryString
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `tbm` query parameter set to the value `isch` for image search. So the minimal URL would look like:

> "[http://google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=](http://google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=imageSearch)" + queryString

Comment: Thank's, this is the URL I needed. Although, this answers only half question. I need to know how can I get content from the page too. For example: I open the given URL and then the user picks an image and the browser closes and returns that image's URL. Maybe I didn't explain well, I'll update my question.